# Angular material two autocomplet fields (optionSelected) not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble re-sending a request after (optionSelected) to update input values for second autocomplete.

I have two autocomplete fields. After changing values in the first one, the second one takes values from api. However, when I delete the value in the first field, the query for the second autocomplete field is not updated.

This is a sample of my code:

```js
  OnProvinceSelected(event) {
    this.provinceId = event.id;
    this.filteredOptionsCountie = this.step.get('province').valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(val => typeof val === 'string' ? val : val.name),
      switchMap(val => {
        return this.filterCountie(val || '');
      }),
      finalize(() => console.log('Sequence complete'))
    );
  }

  filterCountie(val: string): Observable<Location[]> {
    return this.service.getDataCounties(this.provinceId)
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.filter(option => {
          return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0;
        })),
        finalize(() => console.log('Sequence complete'))
      );
  }
```

```html
        <input formControlName="province"
               type="text"
               [matAutocomplete]="provinceA">
        <mat-autocomplete #provinceA="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="OnProvinceSelected($event.option.value)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptionsProvinces | async" [value]="option">
            {{option.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>

        <input formControlName="countie"
               type="text"
               [matAutocomplete]="countieA">
        <mat-autocomplete #countieA="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="OnCountieSelected($event.option.value)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptionsCountie | async" [value]="option">
            {{option.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: You need to add an event listener to the `province` control so that when it gets cleared, you can update the `filteredOptionsCountie` observable. You'd do that this way `(change)="eventHandler($event)"`

Comment: (optionSelected) is doing fine. The problem is with pipe because it's not sending another request after new province is selected.